# Flutter firestore stream for List & Details screens

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm creating an app where I have a listview for user profiles, when you click on a profile it takes you to details screen.

I'm using Firbase stream for the listview as shown below.

**SearchResults.dart**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Profile>>.value(
      value: db.getProfiles(),
      child: ProfileListings(),
    );
  }
```

**ProfileListings.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List profiles = Provider.of<List<Profile>>(context);

    final title = 'Profiles';

    return MaterialApp(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: gridView(profiles),
          drawer: DrawerNav(),
        ),
    );
  }
```

**gridView**

```
 GridView gridView(List<Profile> profiles) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
      children: List.generate(profiles.length, (index) {
        return Center(
          child: Card(
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
            ),
            elevation: 5,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProfileDetails(
                                profileIndex: index,
                                profiles: profiles,
                              )));
                },
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(child: getPhoto(profiles[index])),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(profiles[index].username,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(profiles[index].age,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ])),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Now on the details screen I have a button to edit the profile details. My question is how can I pass the profile from listview to the details screen as a stream without making a separate call to the firestore db?

Since I already have the profiles, I don't want to make individual calls every time when you click to view profile details.

Any suggestions please?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: why not pass them as parameters ?

Comment: how? could you show me code example please?

Comment: ` Class A { Navigator.push ... to your class like this B(yourData); }  Class B{ var yourData; B(@required this.yourData);  }`

Comment: if you want more I can post it as an answer with a working code instead of a hint.

Comment: @Henok sample code would be helpful, thank you. I've added more code details to to my question.

Comment: @Henok your code sample shows passing data from one screen to another but not as a steam. How can I can the data as a stream?